is optional<void> type name valid?
I discovered by accident while modifying existing code that an alias declaration created std::optional<void>. It came from template code like this:
using ret_t = std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Args...>;
using opt_ret_t = std::optional<ret_t>;

The code later discriminates the case when the return type is (not) void, so there is never actually an optional object created.
To make sure I wasn't missing something, I added an assert in that branch of code and everything compiles:
static_assert(std::is_same_v<opt_ret_t, std::optional<void>>);

cppreference says:

There are no optional references, functions, arrays, or cv void; a program is ill-formed if it instantiates an optional with such a type.

So regardless of compilers not complaining, is this code ill-formed?

std::optional has to be able to contain the value. You can't instantiate a void, so I can't see how std::optional could contain a void.

@user4581301 -- it's a type name, there is no object. Type name can participate in many other templates that don't create an object.

So what you're saying is you get to the point of having the name defined, but never used so no optional<void> is instantiated. Hinging on instantiated, should be safe. I added the language-lawyer tag because I figure any answer worth giving is going to have to lean heavily into the interpretations of the Standard.

As long as the instantiation is not ODR-used, you should not encounter the error, which is typically something equivalent to a static_assert(!std::is_void_v<T>) in the class template body that also covers other disallowed types like std::nullopt_t and std::in_place_t.

[res.on.functions]/2.5 states that the behaviour is undefined if you use an incomplete type as a template argument "when instantiating a template component or evaluating a concept, unless specifically allowed for that component" in the standard library.
void is an incomplete type ([basic.types.general]/5), and std::optional is not one of the standard library templates that allows incomplete types ([optional.optional.general]/3). So, if you instantiate std::optional<void>, the program may fail to compile or it may compile and behave unpredictably at runtime (but in practice, the first thing is what happens).
However, doing something like this
using T = std::optional<void>;

does not instantiate std::optional<void>. According to [temp.inst]/2 and [temp.inst]/11, a class template specialization is implicitly instantiated only when it is used in a way that requires the specialization to be complete, or when the completeness of the specialization affects the semantics of the program. When you merely mention the name of a class template specialization or declare an alias for it, the class template specialization doesn't need to be complete, nor is there any difference between declaring an alias to a complete or incomplete type. So in this case we do not get an implicit instantiation.
The standard library does not have a corresponding rule for non-instantiating uses of class template specializations. Indeed, if U is an incomplete class type then it is useful to be able to do something like this:
class U;

std::optional<U> getU();

class U { /* ... */ };
// U is now complete

std::optional<U> getU() {
    // define the function
}

Using a type as a return type doesn't require it to be complete until the function is actually defined, so it's legal to use std::optional<U> as a return type on a non-defining declaration prior to U being completed.
If there were any rule specifically disallowing non-instantiating uses of std::optional<void> in particular, it would need to be found in the description of std::optional itself. Since std::optional is defined as
namespace std {
  template <class T>
  class optional {
      // ...
  };

  // (deduction guide omitted)
}

nothing bad will happen when you merely pass void to the template parameter T without instantiating the class template, but as Davis Herring points out, there could be some class templates where merely mentioning the name of a specialization would be invalid even without instantiation. std::optional just isn't one of them.

There are specific circumstances when (class) templates are implicitly instantiated: see [temp.inst], although in some cases it can vary by implementation.  In no case does merely mentioning a template-id cause instantiation; typically it occurs when the type is required to be complete.
In C++20, it is possible to declare a template with constraints that do take effect even when the template specialization is merely named:
template<class T> requires !std::is_void_v<T>
struct foo {…};


Before C++20 it was possible to cause substitution failure with default template parameters, though for a class template like std::optional, additional template parameters even defaulted would be non-conforming.

@PatrickRoberts: Right, but you could supply an argument to avoid using the default, and as you hint at the different arity would be observable with template template parameters.

std::optional<void> is forbidden by the standard:

T shall be a type other than cv in_place_t or cv nullopt_t that meets
the Cpp17Destructible requirements (Table 32).

Not only is it non-constructable, but because T may not be void, the template itself cannot be instantiated. For instance std::optional<void>::element_type is forbidden, and both MSVC and GCC give appropriate errors.
